# Argo workflow terminates itself after 8 hours

Tags: timeout, argocd, argo-workflows, argo

Currently my argo workflow terminates itself after a max time of 8 hours and can no longer be in suspended state.
With the rollout strategy set as canary, I want the argo workflow to be in suspended state for 2 days and then I will manually resume the workflow.

Can someone help me here?

I tried setting activeDeadlineSeconds to 24 hours but no luck.